# Graphs in matlab and python are different

Tags: python, matlab

I wrote two functions in Matlab, which create graphs. It looks right. But my python code create graphs bad, what my mistake?

My first task

Python code:

```py
def print_two_graph():
    z = np.fft.fft(sin_func, 512)
    pyy = np.conj(z) / 512
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    plt.plot(sin_func, 'green')
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    plt.plot(pyy, 'red')
    plt.show()
```

Matlab code:

```matlab
t = -10:0.1:10;

a = input('Enter a signal: ');
b = input('Enter b signal: ');
c = input('Enter c signal: ');

y = sin(a * t) + 2 * sin(b * t) + 1.5 * sin(c * t);
z = fft(y, 512);
pyy = z.*conj(z) / 512;

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(y, 'g')
subplot(2, 1, 2)
plot(pyy, 'r')
```

[image: Python graph]
[image: Matlab graph]

My second task

Python code:

```py
def print_exp_graph():
    x_range = np.arange(1.0, 10.0, 0.1)
    exp_func = np.exp(x_range)
    plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
    plt.plot(exp_func)
    plt.semilogy(x_range, exp_func)
    plt.show()
```

Matlab code

```matlab
figure

x = 1:0.1:10;
y = exp(x);
subplot(1, 1, 1)
plot(y)
hold on
semilogy(x, y)
legend('Log function', 'Standart function')
```

[image: Second python graph]
[image: Matlab second graph]

How to write equivalent of Matlab code?

Comment: Please add more code to the python example so that anyone can run it (what is `sin_func'?

Comment: Task 1: it seems like in the python code you're only taking the conjugate of z, and in the Matlab code you're multiplying z by the conjugate of z. Shouldn't you also multiply z by the conjugate of z in the python code?

Comment: Task 2: The python plot is semilog on the y axis. In matlab, because you already plot to a regular axis and then `hold on`, the axis is not semilogy. You can verify this by skipping the `plot(y)` line

Comment: Please restrict your questions to _one problem only_.

Answer (score 0):

Task 2: it seems like `semilogy` in Matlab doesn't actually give you a logarithmic scale for the y axis - if you change `plt.semilogy(x_range, exp_func)` to `plt.plot(x_range, exp_func)` you will get the same result as in Matlab - no log scale for the y-axis